# can someone help me detect the error in the necxt code? about strings in c

Tags: c, string, dynamic-memory-allocation

> i need to detect the problem in the next code, and the reason to that  problem and how to fix it. for some reason when i tried to run it in visual the error is on the free.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <malloc.h>
 int main()
 {
  char str1[] = "abcde";
  char* str2 = (char*)malloc(strlen(str1));
  strcpy(str2, str1);
  puts(str1);
  puts(str2);
  free(str2);
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You didn't allocate enough space for the null terminator.

Comment: malloc(strlen(str1) + 1)

Comment: use `strlen+1` or `malloc(sizeof(str1))`

Comment: for the /0? so how come the puts command works? doesn't it prints untill the /0? and there is no /0? and why does the free function needs /0 for? what is the purpose?

Comment: The problem is that you are writing outside the bounds of the buffer. You're probably compiling with debug runtimes and it's warning you that you are doing so. It's for your benefit.

Comment: The `strcpy` is writing past the bounds of the `malloc`ed memory, which may be corrupting the info `free` needs to successfully free that memory. It depends on the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
char* str2 = (char*)malloc(strlen(str1)+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

`strlen` return the length of null terminated string excluding the null character `'\0'`. You need to allocate space for null character too.

```
char* str2 = malloc(strlen(str1) + 1); // Do not cast return value of malloc
```

Comment: but why does the free function needs the null terminator?

Comment: @johnnydoe; That's may be because of undefined behavior.

Comment: I'm guessing the `strcpy` is overwriting the info needed to keep track of the allocation. Actually, I'm guessing it's not *this* allocation that's getting corrupted, but info on the space that's after the allocation. Therefore, when the `free` executes, it's not able to figure out what to do.

Comment: @JohnSensebe; May be the case.

Answer (score 1):

The issue, as others have mentioned, is that you're not allocating enough space for the string you want to copy.  `strlen` returns the number of characters in the string, however that number doesn't include the null byte at the end that terminates the string.

So when you call `strcpy`, you're writing one byte past the end of the allocated memory.  Once you write past your memory bounds, that invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  That means your program might appear to work, it might crash (sometimes right away, sometimes later), or it might cause data corruption that would be hard to detect.

In this particular situation, the extra byte you wrote probably corrupted data used by the implementation of `free` and/or `malloc`.  But with some other compiler or OS, it might work fine.

So to avoid undefined behavior, be sure to allocate the required amount of space:

```
char* str2 = malloc(strlen(str1) + 1);
```

Also, [don't cast the return value of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), as that may mask other errors in your code.